# How to solve looping redirect?

Tags: 301-redirect

I have merged my site from Joomla to WordPress.

Old domain:

1. `www.example.com/about-us.html`
2. `www.example.com/services-skills.html`
3. `www.example.com/services-skills2.html`

New domain:

1. `www.example.com/about-us`
2. `www.example.com/services-skills`
3. `www.example.com/services-skills2`

*.htaccess* configuration:

```
Redirect 301 /example.com/services-skills.html example.com/services-skills
```

and I get a looping error. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To figure out why your redirect is looping you need to see the redirects happening.  One way of doing so is using a command line tool such as curl.   Fetch the head of the page:

```
curl --head http://www.example.com/about-us.html
```

and look for the `Location:` line to see where the redirect goes.  Fetch that URL as well to see where *it* goes.   Keep doing so until you see a loop or a page without a redirect.

You could also use the developer console on Firefox or Chrome that show a list of URLs fetched in the "Network" tab.   I've also relied on the Firefox plugin called "Live HTTP Headers" that show all the headers for requests made in the browser.

In your case you will likely find that your redirect is not going where you think it is.   Based on your rule, I expect your redirect is going to:

```
http:///example.com/example.com/services-skills
```

Because your redirect rule does not use an absolute URL.  This URL must redirect further in some kind of loop.   To fix it, you will need to put the `http://` into your redirect rule:

```
Redirect 301 /example.com/services-skills.html http://example.com/services-skills
```

or take out the `example.com` (as long as you are using a newer version of Apache server (2.4 or later) which has only been out for about a year.

```
Redirect 301 /example.com/services-skills.html /services-skills
```

Rather than implementing separate rules for every page, it might be better to have a [single rule that removes `.html` from every URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245032/url-rewrite-remove-html):

```
redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)\.html$ $1
```

Comment: thanks and this does make a point however I have tried this configuration.....Redirect 301 /services-skills.html htp://example.com/services-skills....and I get error 500

Comment: "htp://"?  That should be "http://".   Look in your server's error_log when you get a 500 error.  That usually has more details about what the problem is.

Comment: I intentionally put "htp://" for the sake of my comment or reply in here since when I put the whole "http://" it will display as a link....

Comment: ok i will try to look at the server side and also is it possible you get looping redirect if the destination URL is the same with the redirected one?  Example:

Redirect 301 /skills-services.html htp://example.com/skills-services
SO the destination URL points to "skills-services"
The same with the Redirected URL "skills-services.html"

Comment: Yes, that would be a redirect loop.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a single rule that can remove all of your `.html` with a single rule and won't cause loops.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the URL in the wordpress dashboard > settings is correct?  That is the most common cause of a redirect loop.

Comment: this is URL settings in Wordpress domain.com/2016/08/03/sample-post

Comment: if htaccess is not possible can this be done via plugin?

Comment: Your URL be the full URL http:// folowed by the domain (I can't type it here without it converting to a link).  There are two fields WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) - that's the place.

Answer (score 0):

You can signal start and end of string:

```
    Redirect 301 ^/example.com/services-skills.html$  example.com/services-skills
Start of string--^        End of search string-----^
```

Comment: so I will add ^ and $ at both ends?

Comment: No, just in your search string (the first one). The dollar alone should solve your problem :)